# Adding Images in radio button list asp.net

Tags: asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I am creating an online examination system in which I need to add images as options to the questions.I have to compulsorily use a radio button list for the same.Following is a piece of code that I wrote for a trial:

```
rblOptions.Items.Add(new ListItem("< img src='" + "~/imgOptions/Ques212Op1.jpg"+"'/ >"));
```

I did not see any image but only a small default icon.What should I do to display images in the radio button list?

Comment: Can you please try with some static url 'https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/32/application_view_detail.png' or "imgOptions/Ques212Op1.jpg" ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
rblOptions.Items.Add(new ListItem("<img src='https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/32/application_view_detail.png' / >"));
//OR
rblOptions.Items.Add(new ListItem("< img src='" + "imgOptions/Ques212Op1.jpg"+"'/ >"));
```